# Convert Listview Entries to Excel then to PDF

Tags: excel, vb.net, pdf

Help me convert list view entries to excel then pdf. Or simply help me convert listview entries to PDF. l am using visual basic 2012. This is the code that l have:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click

        'Export the listview to an Excel spreadsheet
        SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        'exit if no file selected
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'create objects to interface to Excel
        Dim xls As New Excel.Application
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'create a workbook and get reference to first worksheet
        xls.Workbooks.Add()
        book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
        sheet = book.ActiveSheet
        'step through rows and columns and copy data to worksheet
        Dim row As Integer = 1
        Dim col As Integer = 1
        For Each item As ListViewItem In CustomerView.Items
            ' lblID.Text = SalesView.SelectedItems(0).Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
                sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
                col = col + 1
            Next
            row += 1
            col = 1
        Next

        'save the workbook and clean up
        book.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        xls.Workbooks.Close()
        xls.Quit()
        releaseObject(sheet)
        releaseObject(book)
        releaseObject(xls)
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        'Release an automation object
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with? Which concrete line of code?

Comment: If you use Excel interop, this immediately makes your application bad for Web. There are libraries that will do this. Only you will need to serialize your listview into json or xml. And get PDF from there

Comment: You can go directly to PDF without using Excel by using tools like pdfsharp

Comment: Where can l download pdfsharp library free